# "Live concert" versus "Concert"

Tags: meaning

What difference, if any, is there between "Live concert" and "Concert"? As far as I know, 99% of concerts are "live", as opposed to being virtual. Is "Concert" more commonly associated with classical music, with "Live concert" used for other genres such as rock?

Comment: It does seem like a pragmatic (zest-adding) usage rather than a semantically loaded one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of a radio or TV program the qualifier "live" would indicate a *live broadcast* of the concert (as opposed to a replay).  The term "live" is also applied to *recordings* of actual concerts (as opposed to recordings done in a studio).  In general, though, the qualifier "live" in front of "concert" would seem redundant.

Comment: I guess you never went to a Dead concert...